# Subsetting via inner dataframe index using .loc[]

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

```
df.set_index(["breed", "color"])

                name weight
breed     color
Chihuahua Black A    1
          Brown B    2
Labrador  Grey  C    3
Dobberman Brown D    4
```

Is it possible to use `.loc[]` to subset df to only show all "Brown" dogs?

I know per Breed subsetting (i.e. `df.loc["Chihuahua"]`),
and if I try doing inner index subsetting, some sources say that I still need to define the outer index filter (i.e. `df.loc[("Chihuahua", "Brown")]`).

But is there such thing as `df.loc[( , "Brown")]` for all "Brown" dogs subset?